# Qt no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I'm using Qt Creator with Qt 5.9.2, nothing goes wrong.

However, after I switch to Qt 5.10.0 and use static linking, the error appears:

First, `qmake` outputs several lines of `Empty filename passed to function`.

Then, after `make`, the application outputs several lines of `defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"` and crashes.

Is there any solution to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Doing `sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins` worked for me.

Comment: I finally switched back to officially compiled Qt version. Your advice is worth trying if similar problems occur. Thanks.

Comment: That really did it - remind to have gstreamer and plugins installed like described http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html#multimedia-dependencies